# TikZ/Forest: Drawing square arrows that go down and back up

Tags: tikz-arrows, forest

I'm sure there's already an answer for this somewhere but I can't really find it. I'm trying to get square arrows that go down and back up below the tree.

This is what I have right now with the following MVE

```
\begin{forest}
      [AgrO [AgrO,name=AgrO0] { \draw[dashed, <->] (.south) |- (O) node[near end, below] {check}; }
            [\v* [\phantom{\dots}],name=v0
                  [V [\phantom{\dots}] 
                     [\trace{O}, name=O] 
                  ]
            ]
      ]
\end{forest}
```

[image]

I want something more like this (MS Paint approximation)

[image]

Comment: Instead of (not working) code fragment you should provide complete small document with `forest` diagram. Therefore, all definitions and used libraries are unknown to us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>=Straight Barb}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[AgrO
    [AgrO,name=AgrO0]
    [$v$
      [\phantom{V}]
      [V
        [\phantom{t}]
        [to,name=O]
      ]
    ]
]
  \draw[<->,densely dashed] (O) -- ++ (0,-1) -| (AgrO0)
    node[pos=0.25,below] {check};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same result can be achieved without `linguistics` library, however than you need to define nodes anchors accordingly:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>=Straight Barb}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree = {parent anchor=south,
            child anchor=north}
% tree body
```